# Build Jest as UMD module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Hi I am trying to add jest to my existing application.
Unfortunately I am not using any create-react-app,webpack, npm to install and bundle.

React and ReactDOM from : https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js
Enzyme from this site : https://gist.github.com/jonmbake/6362a9f54f57a4506057166aa5ec7027
In package json of enzyme modified the build script by adding "&& babel build -d babel" (which did compilation from ES5-ES6)

Similarly looking for jest.js to use in my test for async call.

(Would like to use jest.setTimeout)

Comment: Jest is Node.js library, not browser. You cannot avoid using NPM. If you want to run tests with a browser alone, consider using Jasmine.

Comment: @EstusFlask actually i haven't used Jasmine before.i was going thrugh the doc but i couldnt find so far how can i install and build jasmine as UMD. any lead or hint is appreciated.

Comment: @EstusFlask here you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67208176/settimeout-in-enzyme-jest i am trying to solve this  issue in my test.

Comment: See https://jasmine.github.io/pages/getting_started.html regarding standalone version. I'd say that you're trying to do is very exotic and counterproductive, consider sticking to conventional Jest workflow if you're serious about testing.